# I can't use search button for Google Maps module - Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click on the google maps feature in yard Matrix and have tried a couple of ways. The code I am using is
driver.find_element_by_name('Choose a starting point...').send_keys(address)
I believe the problem is the google maps tool is embedded in the website. I think I am missing a step by not identifying the tool first.

Comment: Please post your code and relevant html

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.